Handle scrolling and height with multiple collectionviews on one page in dotNET MAUI
I've got a horizontally oriented (on top) and a vertically oriented (below) CollectionView on the same page. I would like the page to scroll down infinitely but the bottom CollectionView does not allow this. For some reason it gets a small, fixed height and does not fill the page.
I tried both with and without a parent ScrollView. How do I make the page scroll infinitely with both the horizontally oriented and vertically oriented CollectionView on it?
(see code and illustrations below)
XAML attempt 1:
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <CollectionView>
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    </CollectionView>
    <CollectionView>
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    </CollectionView>
</VerticalStackLayout>

XAML attempt 2:
<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView>
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView>
        <CollectionView>
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>

This is how my views are scrolling:
Notice how the vertically oriented CollectionView (V) does not fill the page.

This is how I want my views to scroll:
Notice how you can continue to scroll down the entire page infinitely.


you shouldn't nest one scrollable element within another

I don't think you are designing this correctly you should be using two separate scrollable controls, and not nest them

Thanks @Jason and FreakyAli. Using a (vertical)stacklayout instead of the scrollview produces similar results as the first image. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get the page to scroll as in the second image?

This will not be able to work like the second image. The collectionview can scroll itself and you can not put it in the ScrollView again to make it scrollable.

@GuangyuBai-MSFT So there is absolutely no way to do this? I could give the second collectionview a fixed HeightRequest higher than the space between the first collectionview and the bottom of the page, but it's far from ideal.

It is indeed discouraged to nest scrollable views in .NET MAUI. Since ScrollViews are unrestrained, doing otherwise would make sizing children that are also unrestrained difficult.
The closest you could probably get to your desired design (based on how I understand it) would be by constraining the outer ScrollView to scroll vertically only and then adding a Grid inside with two rows. In the first row, you could add a CollectionView that only allows scrolling horizontally, which at the same time must have a fixed height. In the second row, which could be infinite in size, you could then have a VerticalStackLayout coupled with a BindableLayout in order to display any data you want to bind to vertically:
XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
  x:Class="NestedScrollSample.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
  x:Name="MyPage">

  <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="120,*">

      <CollectionView
        Grid.Row="0"
        HeightRequest="120"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
        BackgroundColor="Orange">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
          <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="system:String">
            <Grid
              WidthRequest="300"
              HeightRequest="100"
              VerticalOptions="Center">
              <Label Text="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      </CollectionView>

      <VerticalStackLayout
        Grid.Row="1"
        BackgroundColor="Aqua"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="system:String">
            <Grid HeightRequest="300">
              <Label Text="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
      </VerticalStackLayout>

    </Grid>

  </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

Code-behind
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace NestedScrollSample;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyStrings { get; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        MyStrings = new()
        {
            "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwx", "yz!"
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

This way, you can have a nested setup, which circumvents the issues that typically arise when doing so.
Disclaimer: This code is purely for demonstration purposes, it doesn't follow any design guidelines, recommendations or development patterns. I also only tested this on Android and Windows, but it should work on all supported platforms like this.

Thanks a million! Never considered using a BindableLayout here but it works exactly as expected. It even has more advantages that I was still looking for. Such as bottom margins/paddings so the last item in the list won't hide partly behind a floating action button if you scrolled all the way down.
